# Почему не открывается в мобильной версии Bootstrap navbar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

```
base.html

<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/slick/slick.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/slick/slick-theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/main.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

    {% block title %}{% endblock %}
    <title>{{ page_title }}</title>
</head>

<body>
    {% include 'menu.html' %} {% block body %}{{ heading }}{% endblock %}

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/slick/slick.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/slick/slider.js"></script>
    введите сюда код
    <footer><br><br>
        <div class="container" style="color:#0000CD;">
            <div class="row">введите сюда код
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-6">
                    <div class="f-box left">
                        <div class="phone-box">
                            <i class="demo-icon app-phone"></i>
                            <a href="tel:+7"><span>Телефон: 8 977</span> </a>
                            <p>115201. Москва<br><br>дом 3, офис 49</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.6.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-KsvD1yqQ1/1+IA7gi3P0tyJcT3vR+NdBTt13hSJ2lnve8agRGXTTyNaBYmCR/Nwi" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-nsg8ua9HAw1y0W1btsyWgBklPnCUAFLuTMS2G72MMONqmOymq585AcH49TLBQObG" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
</body>

</html>




menu.html

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <strong><em><a class="nav-link" href="/">МИР ДВЕРЕЙ</a></em></strong>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/glass"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary"><em>Межкомнатные двери</em></button></a>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/peregorodki"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary"><em>Перегородки</em></button></a>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/sauna"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary"><em>Для сауны и бани</em></button></a>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/showers"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary"><em>Душевые ограждения</em></button></a>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/mirrors"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary"><em>Зеркала</em></button></a>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/constructions"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary"><em>Стеклянные конструкции</em></button></a>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="/delivery"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary"><em>Доставка</em></button></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href=""><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary"><em> Телефон:<br>
                </em></button></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Эти товарищи за какой-то непонятной надобностью в 5-й версии добавили в дата-атрибуты префикс -bs-, и без него новый 5-й js-бандл не работает (можно пользоваться старым, 4-м). Теперь нужно писать `data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"`:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
  integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <strong><em><a class="nav-link" href="/">МИР ДВЕРЕЙ</a></em></strong>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/glass"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary"><em>Межкомнатные двери</em></button></a>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/peregorodki"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary"><em>Перегородки</em></button></a>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/sauna"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary"><em>Для сауны и бани</em></button></a>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/showers"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary"><em>Душевые ограждения</em></button></a>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/mirrors"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary"><em>Зеркала</em></button></a>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/constructions"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary"><em>Стеклянные конструкции</em></button></a>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="/delivery"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary"><em>Доставка</em></button></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href=""><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary"><em> Телефон:<br>
                </em></button></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Меню заработала. Странно как-то. Я его внес в свой код и он не работает, а сделал другой hnml  тест, там все работает. Не знаете в чем еще может быть причина?

Comment: @Игорёк, ещё причина может быть в том, что бутстрап требует подключения jquery - у Вас подключена библиотека?

Comment: Тоже про это слышал. Вроде нет, точно не могу сказать. Я новичок и не могу точно на все отвечать. Через pip install jquery   или он еще где-то в html должен быть?

Comment: @Игорёк я в Питон не умею, так что насчет pip install ничего сказать не могу. Подключите туда же, куда Вы бутстраповский бандл подключаете (только перед ним).

Comment: Я как понимаю у меня base.html  подключен jquery

Comment: @Игорёк, если Вы про код, который в вопросе, то там зачем-то аж 2 раза подключены разные версии jquery. Оставьте только одну, самую свежую.

Comment: К сожалению не помогает. Убрал один и все равно не работает((((

Comment: Ураааа))) Не знаю что и как там произошло. Я что-то еще отключил и сейчас все работает. Тебе огромное СПАСИБО!!!!! Без твоей помощь, точно не получилось бы. Гуглил и советы давали.... твое решение все-таки помогло.

Comment: @Игорёк, если ответ помог, прими его, поставив галочку )

Comment: С удовольствием. Только не могу понять где галочку поставить.)